# Importing Openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

Hello I am new to coding and I am trying to open an excel file. I've install the module for openpyxl and I know have at least somewhere because every time I type in command prompt pip install openpyxl it says it exists. But when I try to use it in my visual studio code it doesn't seem to be recognizing it. I know this is probably a rookie mistake and something super simple to fix but any help is greatly appreciated.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/24BFv.png)

I was just trying to see if I could write to it but I am cautious before proceeding with my code, thank you again.

Comment: Which version of Python are you using, and is the package installed for that version (e.g. not Python 2.x)? Are you using a virtual environment?

Answer (score 0):

Test by creating a virtual environment,there you will be able to make better use of the versions of each library.

https://docs.python.org/es/3/tutorial/venv.html

however, I recommend that you use pandas to read your excel file. (pip install pandas)

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_excel(file directory)
```

Comment: Pandas uses openpyxl so the problem will this wouldn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If use the shortcut Ctrl+Shift+p in Visual studio code and Select interpreter, Then select the version of python you want to use, Then open a terminal in visual studio code and type> pip freeze into the terminal and you will be able to see if openpyxl is installed, Hope this helps.
[image]
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F2koj.png)

[image]